# Merge duplicates in list

Tags: java, list

I have a list of some strings. I need to merge dublicates and add counter of duplicates. For example:

```
list1.add("Mom");
list1.add("Mom");
list1.add("Son");
list1.add("Son");
list1.add("Dad");
list1.add("Dad");
```

merge and add counter

and output needs to be like this:

```
Mom 2
Son 2
Dad 2
```

Also I need to sort this new list, but I think I can just use collections, to do that.

Comment: Being picky here but does the output need to be in that particular order, or would alphabetic (or even arbitrary) be permissible?

Comment: And what have you tried yet? And why haven't you tried anything yet?

Comment: Ideally, it should be sorted in ascending order, but I know how to do it.

Answer (score 5):

```
public static Map<String, Long> getValuesWithNumberOfOccurrences(
        List<String> list) {
    return list.stream()
               .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, HashMap::new,
                    Collectors.counting()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `HashMap` to keep duplicates:

```
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        String text = list.get(i);
        if(map.get(text) == null) {
            map.put(text, 1);
        } else {
            map.put(text, map.get(text) + 1);
        }
    }

    for (String text : map.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(text + " " + map.get(text));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the output order needs to respect the order in which the keys were first encountered. Fortunately the clever Java bods designed an object for that: `java.util.LinkedHashMap`.

To set up your storage object use

`java.util.Map<String, Integer> map = new java.util.LinkedHashMap<>()`

Note the fancy diamond notation.

Then, with `name` as a string, write something like

```
if (map.containsKey(name)){
    map.put(key, map.get(key) + 1);
} else {
    map.put(key, 1);
}
```

This could be optimised a little: you could rely on the fact that `map.get(key)` will be `null` if `key` is not present. This obviates the need for the `containsKey` call.

Finally, to output your values use something on the lines of

```
for (java.util.Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()){
    /*ToDo - use entry.getKey() and entry.getValue()*/
}
```

If you want your output to be sorted on the keys then use a `java.util.TreeMap` instead. If the order of output is of no consequence to you then use a `java.util.HashMap`.

Answer (score -1):

> I need to merge duplicates and add counter of duplicates.

When duplicate stuff comes to mind, think of `Set` to isolate. As and when you try to add an element to set and the `add` method returns `false`, print the data with 2 count.

But when the entries can occur more than twice, then you need to keep a track of each entry's count until the very end. So use a map instead with each String as key and its count as value. That basically means, while adding a string to map:

Get it from the map
  - if not null, then get its value, increment 1 and set its value again.
  - if null, then add it to map with value=1

At the end, you can iterate and find count.